# Finding relevant keyword from a webpage

Tags: java, javascript, search, lucene

- On a side I have a Java CMS providing a Set of keywords
- On the other side I have a JavaScript Bookmarklet to curate a Webpage

Is there a clever way to cross/match my set of keywords with the webpage content ?

John Resign explain [in some articles](http://ejohn.org/blog/revised-javascript-dictionary-search/) how to compress then search in a Dictionary terms but it seems really complicated.

In fact, I'm looking for a clever Java or JavaScript algorithm to match a Set of String in a text efficiently.

My question is very close to this one:
[Effective search on a small text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664227/effective-search-on-a-small-text)

But,

- I want to do it on 1 text instead of a database of texts
- Indexing with lucene works great but I don't know how to match efficiently indexed terms with all my keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have done some proof of concept based on Lucene indexed Set.

- It handle all language/text issues
- It is fast enought

But a good answer needs a large relevant content. So results are sometimes stranges. And it's server side...

Answer (score 0):

You could use java like this:

```
Set<String> keywords = new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList("keyword1", "keyword2"));
String content = "your doc here with keyword1 etc";
Set<String> contentWords = new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(content.split(" ")));
contentWords.retainAll(keywords); 
// now contentWords contains only words from keywords, in this case just "keyword1"
```

if you want to get all the words from content that are *not* keywords, use this instead:

```
contentWords.removeAll(keywords);
```

Using `TreeSet` should make it perform pretty well.

This code, which compiles and runs, has been simplified for illustration. You would have to load your keywords from a DB etc and load your content from wherever etc.

Comment: It's a little bit too straight forward ? You do not remove stop word, in multilang, case insensitive. retainAll() algorithm will do 2 loops